# When are temporary files deleted when I upload them?

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring 2.4.4 webflux.

Uploading files accumulates files in temporary storage, but the accumulated files remain, not deleted.

The rest of the files grew and became a problem for the service.

I have checked the part where I am processing using FilePart and where temporary files are stored, but I want to know when and in what format these temporary files are deleted.

```
@RestController
class FileController() {
    @RequestMapping("/file", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    fun fileUpload(@RequestBody fileRequest: MultiValueMap<String, Part>) = "completed"
}
```

[temp files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLS1n.png)

If anyone knows please help